# Автозаполнение кода из смс на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

В ios работает автозаполнение кода подтверждения при получении смс на большинстве сайтов, делаю то же самое у себя, на момент получения юзер находится на странице с одним инпутом под код и кнопкой submit, в смс содержится просто четырехзначный код подтверждения. Собственно проблема в том, что система не предлагает вставить из сообщений его, а спецификации по формату смс я так и не нашел. Может кто делал что подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в тексте смс укажите сайт, где требуется вставить код, это проверка